# ADLS Gen 2 Storage API - Refusing Http Verbs

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm having a problem with some endpoints within the [ADLS Gen 2 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) Path operations.

I can create, list, get properties of, and delete file systems just fine.

However, after adding a directory to a file system, certain verbs are failing - HEAD, GET, and DELETE.

For example, I have created a filesystem named c79b0781, with a directory path of abc/def

> Call failed with status code 400 (The HTTP verb specified is invalid - it is not recognized by the server.): DELETE https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781/abc?recursive=true&timeout=30

For headers, I have:

> x-ms-version: 2018-11-09

I can delete the filesystem from the Azure Storage Explorer, but the API is refusing my query.

The List action is also failing with a similar error

> Call failed with status code 400 (The HTTP verb specified is invalid - it is not recognized by the server.): GET https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?resource=filesystem&recursive=false&timeout=30

With headers:

> x-ms-version: 2018-11-09

And finally, my Get Properties is also failing

> Call failed with status code 400 (The HTTP verb specified is invalid - it is not recognized by the server.): HEAD https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?resource=filesystem&timeout=30

It seems to only happen when I add directories to the file system.

**A bit more in depth:**

This Test works

> PUT https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?resource=filesystem
>   GET https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?recursive=false&resource=filesystem
>   DELETE https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?resource=filesystem

My second Test with directory creation

> PUT https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?resource=filesystem
>   PUT https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781/abc/123?resource=directory

After this point, the calls begin rejecting HTTP verbs

> GET https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781?recursive=false&resource=filesystem

Examining my directory create request closer, it looks like this:

PUT https://myadls.dfs.core.windows.net/c79b0781/abc/123?resource=directory

With Headers:

> Authorization: [omitted]
>   Content-Length: 0

And I can see the folders in Storage explorer, I just cannot act on them after this point.

**Test Case 2**

I have started down a path wondering if it is permissions.  So, I created a new File System through the Azure Storage Explorer with abc/def folder structure within.

Test 1 (passing)

> Get List for directory "abc"
>   Get List for directory "abc/def"

Test 2 (failing)

> Create Directory "uvw/xyz"
>   Get List for directory "abc"  **Fails here**
>   Get List for directory "abc/def"
>   Get List for directory "uvw/xyz"

Once I create a directory through the api, it is as if the entire filesystem begins rejecting all HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug ended up leading me down a rabbit hole into my Flurl implementation that I am using for performing rest requests.

The Put method had no body and was calling `PutJsonAsync` where [according to the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create), it expects the content type to be `application/octet-stream` with content length 0.

I replaced the call to `PutJsonAsync` to `PutAsync` and everything magically started working.

So, there seems to be some bug within Flurl itself that caused this issue, due to my misuse in my wrapper code.